# Calculate mod in casio fx-991ES PLUS, answer given is wrong

Tags: math, calculator, modulo

when I'm using my calculator to calculate mod, until now it have been giving me right answers, until I reached this problem that said:
5^-1 mod 18 = 11
my calculator kept given the answer to be number one instead.
Can this kind of problems (where b > a) be solved using a calculator??

*please note that I'm using the calculator in ab/c mode and it's solving problems fine until now.

Comment: 5^-1 is 1/5, right? shouldn't 1/5 mod 18 be just 1/5? Or are you using the caret to indicate bitwise XOR, not exponentiation? Wouldn't it be 12 then?

Comment: @Kevin OP probably means a modular inverse (ie 5 * 11 mod 18 = 1, so 5^-1 mod 18 = 11)

Comment: yes 5^-1 is 1/5 and not XOR. How can that be calculated?

Comment: 1/5 is meaningless when you deal with mod... it only works with integers.  So 5^-1 mod 18 means the number that you have to multiply 5 by to get 1 mod 18, in other words 11.  The calculator is right.

Comment: @TravisJ Maybe make an answer out of this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1/5 is meaningless when you deal with mod, since it only works with integers.

When you write `5^-1 mod 18`, it means the modular inverse of 5, in other words "the number by which you have to multiply 5 to get 1 mod 18".

> 5 * 11 = 55 = 3 * 18 + 1 = 1 mod 18

Thus the calculator is right.

---

As a side note, note that when the modulo is not prime, the modular inverse doesn't always exist. In particular, `a` has a modular inverse modulo `b` if and only if `a` and `b` are coprime.

For example, when you multiply 9 by an even number you always get 0 mod 18, and by an uneven number 9 mod 18. Thus no number yields 1, and can be the modular inverse of 9 modulo 18.